# Google charts Legend spacing Issue

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am trying to configure google charts in My application but facing a wierd issue.

Legend is condensed and overlapping.

These are my options

```
var options = {
            fontName: 'Roboto',
            height: 400,
            fontSize: 12,
            chartArea: {
                left: '8%',
                width: '100%',
                height: 350
            },
            isStacked: true,
            tooltip: {
                textStyle: {
                    fontName: 'Roboto',
                    fontSize: 12
                }
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: '',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    italic: false
                },
                gridlines:{
                    color: '#f5f5f5',
                    count: 10,
                },
                // format: '$#,###',
                minValue: 0,
                // ticks: [0,10,20,30]

            },
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                alignment: 'right',
                // textStyle: {
                //     fontSize: 13
                // }
            },
            colors: [ '#f9c003','#487ee2','#487ee2']
        };
```

But getting results like this

[image]

Comment: Can you share the complete function which generates the chart ?

Comment: Using your options for the chart, I don't see such overlaps. See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz0v16yp/)

Comment: this happens when the chart is drawn in a hidden container...